# Incorrect "Google Maps" section in Gmail contact

Tags: google-maps, google-contacts

My contact suddenly has a new section titled "Google Maps" and this section shows information for a random business located in another state (this "Google Maps" section is between "Contact details" and "Google profile".

When I click on a link icon within this section, it takes me to the Maps listing for this business. AS far as I can tell, there is nothing in there that could possibly link my contact to it.

It's important for me to fix this because I have a business and this messes with my local SEO. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is there a pic attached to the contact that might have some incorrect EXIF data?

Comment: Is your [web activity](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/54068) turned on?

Comment: Contact picture is a professional studio headshot, EXIF data for location isn't present. Web activity has been turned off for years. But thank you for the suggestions!